# ¿ Cómo inserto un campo que tiene guion en mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quiero insertar un valor a un campo `varchar` , este valor tiene un guion al medio `(7-2017)` pero al insertar me sale un advertencia , se inserta pero solo sale lo que esta antes del guion es decir el 12, y lo demás no se inserta

**Insert**

```
insert into motivo(cod_movilidad,fecha_motivo,desc_motivo,desde,hasta,monto_gastado) 
           values ('7-2017','2017-06-06','sdad','dasd','dsqad','12')
```

el error que me sale

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column
>   'cod_movilidad' at row 1

Comment: ¿Por casualidad el campo `cod_movilidad` está definido como `varchar(2)`? ¿Cuál es el largo permitido por ese campo?

Comment: Puedes incluir en la pregunta la definición de tu tabla?

Answer (score 2):

Tu varchar tiene un limite lo que hace que se corte, por ejemplo `varchar(2)`. Por eso le hace un `truncate`.

Deberías definirla como `varchar(250)`.

Comment: Jaime que tal :D si pudieses copiar este texto y colocarlo como comentario debajo de la pregunta, puesto que no es una respuesta :D

Comment: No puedo comentar y quería ayudar, eliminare la respuesta, acabo de ver la edición, queda mejor, gracias!

Comment: No veo por que esto es de baja calidad. La única razón por la que se [truncan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_warn_data_truncated) los datos es por que el campo no tiene la capacidad necesaria.

Comment: @Arie porque entró en revisión como NeuR, fijate la primera versión... Mi edición apuntó a salvarla.

Comment: Lo siento, es que estaba en la lista de revisiones. :p

Answer (score 1):

**El problema no es el guión**, el problema es que el valor se esta truncando

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column
>   'cod_movilidad' at row 1

si se inserta únicamente lo que esta antes del guión probablemente tienes definido `CHAR(2)`.

Debes definir una longitud correcta en tu campo para contener ese tipo de dato, por ejemplo aumenta a `CHAR(10)` para que no se trunque.